# Proof Check: What's the minimal n that the quadratic form $10x^2-12xy+5y^2 = n$ gets?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Firstly, I noticed that by plugging in $(1,1)$ I could get $n=3$. 
Next, the quadratic form is positive-definite because $a=10>0$ and $b^2-4ac = 144-4*(10)*(5) = -56 <0$. This means that the form can only return positive numbers, meaning I only have to check that the form doesn't have solutions for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

The form has solutions iff the congruency $x^2 = 56 mod(4*n)$ has solutions. 
For $n=1$, $x^2 =2(mod4)$ has no solutions after checking all 4 elements.

For $n=2$: Does $x^2 = 56mod(8) = 0mod(8)$ have a solution? Only if $x = 0$ **.

So I proved that the minimal n is 3 and is gotten by plugging ing $(1,1)$.

I have 2 questions about this proof. Firstly about line **: the congruency has a solution, but 10x^2-12xy+5y^2 = 2 does not, what can explain this inconsistency?

My second question is this: Is this a vaild proof? I guessed a solution and got a low n, so it was easy to check that it was indeed a solution, but would this be accepted on a test?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: At some point, you should explicitly say you are only interested in integer $x,y$. Otherwise, the form *does* take on the value 1, at $(x,y)=(1/\sqrt{13})(2,3)$.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you do when $n=1$; 56 is 0 (mod 4), not 2 (mod 4).

Comment: Do you know the wonderful http://www.amazon.com/Sensual-Quadratic-Carus-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0883850303?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are correct, it's my mistake.

Comment: Alternately, LHS $=(3x-2y)^2+x^2+y^2>2$ is easy to see for natural numbers $x,y$.

Comment: @Macavity Not too sure if $x, y$ are limited to natural numbers, since that was not explicitly stated. Though however, since OP did congruence relations, that seems to be an implicit assumption.

Comment: Why can't we use $(0,0)$ to get 0? Can you please clarify what the restrictions on $x, y, n$ are? (see above comment)

Comment: @Calvin et al, the usual conventions are these: when discussing quadratic forms $Q(x)$ over the reals, $x$ in ${\bf R}^n$,  restrict to unit vectors $x$; when discussing quadratic forms over the integers, restrict to $x\ne0$. OP has not made the restrictions explicit, but one can guess from context.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested, here's another way to do it.

Rewrite as $$(10x-6y)^2+14y^2=10n$$ Now it's easy to show there are no solutions for $n=1,2$ by inequalities, rather than congruences. E.g., for $n=2$, the left side exceeds the right unless $y=0$ or $y=\pm1$, and these $y$-values require 20 or 6 to be a square.

Comment: Is there any general theory on this? For example, suppose $(V,Q)$ is a quadratic module over a *sufficient good ring* $R$, say, $R=\mathbb Z$, or generally a PID, is there any theory on the canonical form of $Q$, just like when $R$ is a field, $V=k_1x_1^2+\dotsb+k_nx_n^2$.

Comment: @Frank, I know there is such a thing for binary quadratic forms over the integers, but that's where I stop knowing.

Comment: There seem some results in J.P.Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic*, Chapter V. It's a tough book to me.